# jquery Ajax goes to a blank page

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

jquery is powerful but has a many different problems.
i have this code:

```
 $(
     function () {
         // Get a reference to the content div (into which we will load content).
         var jContent = $("#content");

         // Hook up link click events to load content.
         $("ul li a").click(
             function () {
                 var jLink = $(this);

                 // Clear status list.
                 $("#ajax-status").empty();

                 // Launch AJAX request.
                 $.ajax({
                     // The link we are accessing.
                     url: jLink.attr("href"),

                     // The type of request.
                     type: "GET",

                     // The type of data that is getting returned.
                     dataType: "html",


                     error: function () {
                         ShowStatus("AJAX - error()");

                         // Load the content in to the page.
                         jContent.html("<p>Page Not Found!!</p>");
                     },

                     beforeSend: function () {
                         ShowStatus("AJAX - beforeSend()");
                     },

                     complete: function () {
                         ShowStatus("AJAX - complete()");
                     },

                     success: function (strData) {
                         ShowStatus("AJAX - success()");
                         jContent.html($(strData).find('#bglogin').html());
                     }
                 });

                 // Prevent default click.
                 return (false);
             }
         );

     }
 );
```

when i use it on my blog it goes to a blank white page. i change it many times, but it does not work. but, when i use it on a blank page, (use this code only for blog) it works and a new problem. 
we think in this page: /login
there are these tags:

```
<div id="login">
   <div id="bglogin">
     <p>hello</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

when i call the jquery `(jContent.html($( strData ).find('#bglogin').html());)` that get `#bglogin` id, it get the code, but, when i want the `#login` id,
it doesn't get me anything.

Answer (score 0):

Dont think its the problem, but you should not use reaturn false. This would be the proper method

```
$("ul li a").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // this will stop default behaviour.
    var jLink = $(this);
});
```

Comment: but still goes to a white page

Comment: What does your console say? Maybe a JS error, 404 for the file (should not goto a blank page tho)
What if you remove the ajax, see if it still does that. If not, make the ajaxcall the most simplified manner you can make it. Just keep adding code untril it breaks

Comment: sometimes when i change the code it goes to a blank page.but now it doesn't. now go to this page:http://nowsud.rozblog.com/ and see the problem (the page is to ..., sorry!). the content #left-sidebar of that page is not load. sorry for bad english. can you fix this problem????

Comment: The external javascript is giving an error, but thats not it. I think you choose the wrong selector. If I place this after the first `function(){` : `$("ul li a").css('backgroundColor','pink');` no anchor turns pink. If I change it to $("a") all anchors do. Your ajaxcall is not working on those anchors because you have a wrong selector

Comment: ok, i'm for that code call the jquery only when click on a link that there is in the ul li directory run the ajax, now why the code is not working? thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

With this html:

```
<div id="login">
   <div id="bglogin">
     <p>hello</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

This javascript

```
$(strData).find('#login').html()
```

does not give you anything because the `find` method looks for the **child elements** and your root element in this case is `#login`. You're looking for a `child` with id `#login` from the `#login` element, the code cannot find it. That's why it does not work. In this case, just simply write:

```
jContent.html(strData);
```

Comment: @ARAS: if you have many tags on the same levels. For example: `<div id="login></div> <div id="other"></div>`. You could try: `$(strData).filter('#login').html()`

Comment: I think you should try this
 $("ul li a").click(
             function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
...
}

Comment: @Dieter Pollier: `return false;` should also prevent default.