# Ajax: in case of GET request, the page clears

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**EcmaScript 6, jQuery 3.1.0**

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kifsif/k6gw1gnw/10/

Heroku: https://morning-headland-78510.herokuapp.com/frame/1/

There is a plus sign on the page. Clicking it should add a form right above the plus.

The problem is that when I add a form via AJAX, it is shown on a blank page.

Well, I can't imitate it in Fiddle. In the fiddle the page is not cleared. In other words, in the Fiddle everything is correct, like I want it to be.

Please, in Chrome or other browser open debugger. I have placed two breakpoints.

In the debugger at breakpoint 1:

```
this._url = "/frame/1/frame_date_create/"
```

I checked without AJAX. Look: https://morning-headland-78510.herokuapp.com/frame/1/frame_date_create/.

The form appears correctly. This means that server seems to response correctly.

As for working via AJAX, **the trouble is that the page clears and the form appears alone before the user. On a clear page.**

What the form returned by the server looks like is shown below in the code section. Status is 200.

Let's return to JavaScript. The success function is empty. It should show the form in the appropriate place, but in this case it contains just a breakpoint.

In the debugger the troubles continue. At breakpoint 2, usually the page is already cleared, and form is already on the screen. But sometimes the page at breakpoint 2 is not cleared yet. This difference in the behaviour astonishes me a bit.

I have created a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhEZVBCK_hw

Unfortunately, the cursor is not visible. At 0:28 is a case when I'm at breakpoint 2, but the page is still unchanged.

Usually clearing the page in case of AJAX requests happens in case of POST request. I managed to find one question on Stackoverflow about such case for GET request: [jquery Ajax goes to a blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511913/jquery-ajax-goes-to-a-blank-page)

Could you help me understand what is going on here, where I have made mistakes and how to solve the problem.

```
<form id="object_form" action="/frame/1/frame_date_create/" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="9UWsO6nYgQYHvo0W1QdclHG229IkaDV01YWl4j2Ug1DSOEf4kG5X87vZSsNNWre8">
            <table>
                <tbody><tr><th><label for="id_date">Date:</label></th><td><input id="id_date" name="date" placeholder="ГГГГ-ММ-ДД" type="text" required=""></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="id_precision">Точность:</label></th><td><select id="id_precision" name="precision" required="">
    <option value="">----</option>
    <option value="F">Month</option>
    <option value="Y">Year</option>
    <option value="d">Day</option>
    </select><input id="id_frame" name="frame" type="hidden" value="21"></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
        <a id="submit" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" aria-hidden="true">Save</span></a>


        <a id="cancel" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</span></a>

</form
```

>

```
class CreateManager{

...

    _send_get_request(){
        debugger; // 1
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: this._url,
            dataType: "html",
            success: this._show_form.bind(this),
            error: general_fail
        });
    }

    _show_form(data){
        debugger; // 2
        // let element = $('#' + this._data_table);
        // element.after(data);
        // this._button_manager.handle_cancel();
        // this._button_manager.handle_submit(this._send_post_request.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you console.log (event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-table");) and tell me what the output is?

Comment: It evaluates to "framedate_ul". I need the element with id "framedate_ul" for placing the form to its appropriate place.

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: Line 63 change it to this `let id = $('#frame_date_create').attr("data-table");` and then line 98 change it to `element.replaceWith(data);` => The cause is previous code is replacing the whole `body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**remove the `control` class from the `frame_date_create` button** you are triggering both the click event for the add and the click event for update, this does 2 ajax calls, the ajax call for the update appends the ajax result to the dom document

Comment: The first method doesn't seem to have  helped. Please, have a look again at Heroku. Have I understood you correctly? And I can't catch your idea. data_table="framedate_ul". In your case and in my case. It is just a string. We don't even rely on it anywhere. We will when it comes to placing the form. But the problem so far is clearing the page.

Comment: from what i can see you are doing 2 ajax calls why?

Comment: $(event).attr("data-table") returned undefined. Well, I commented it out and return your first variant.

Comment: 2 ajax calls: in class CreateManager they are at line 152 and line 173. Well, they are for get and post methods. This is my first experience with ajax. How can I use one? They are so different: post request needs data. By the way, a bit higher in the code there is UpdateDeleteManager. It is similar. It is now not activated. I commented out that functionality. But when it worked, it worked correctly: without making the page blank.

Comment: there are 2 get requests no post request

Comment: I can't catch your idea. Isn't it a post request at line 173. Well, and what can it change? I don't send post request here. I only want to receive a form via get request and place it to its place.

Comment: I tried. Made a syntax error somewhere and noticed that even with the error the form appeared. Well, when did I manage to request it? Could you have a look at heroku.  _send_get_request() is absolutely empty now.

Comment: it seems you trigger the ajax request from the update button, why?

Comment: update button leads to UpdateDeleteManager. Well, that class issues its own get and post requests. How can I update otherwise? But what about update? If there is no data, for example, nothing to update. Only plus sign will be visible. I have to check classes of the plus sign. Maybe it somehow triggers UpdateDeleteManager.

Comment: you used the class that you bind the update to the create button, and you where doing 2 ajax calls one for create and one for update

Comment: why do you use classes for dom manipulation?, i find it very hard to read your code

Comment: Working. Thank you. If you organize this as an answer, I would gladly accept it. You helped me a lot.

Comment: Classes for dom manipulation I use because there supposed to be several plus buttons.  For this heroku example excessive functionality was commented out. They are all of create class. I couldn't invent anything better. Is it a malpractice?

Comment: By the way, did you notice 2 get requests in Chrome at Network tab? I have never used it so far. I'll pay attention to it.

Comment: yes i noticed 2 get requests didn't know you where using the same form for update as well, i have never seen someone use classes for simple dom manipulation,i usually use 2-3 click events and be done with it, less code, cleaner and more manageable,and very easy to debug

Comment: well, there are a lot of controls: icons for creation, updating and deletion of different objects. They are all combined as "control" class. When a form appears, all buttons with "control" class disappear. $(".control").addClass("hide"). Buttons for creation, deletion and updating again represent their own classes. Depending on the class I call different JS methods. Classes are convenient for this purpose. I can't think of anything better. Of course lack of experience have had effect in this case. Several days I've been solving this problem. You teach me a lot this time. Thank you very much.